# AlaSQL inserting into table from CSV doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sql, csv, alasql

Trying to copy CSV data to internal table of AlaSQL.
But `SELECT * INTO tab FROM CSV()` - simply doesn't work. Nothing changed after this. Table `tab` still empty, but direct select works fine. What i'm doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="res1"></div>
  <div id="res2"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.3.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
  
 <script type="text/sql" id='sql'>
  CREATE table tab(c1 integer);
  
  select count(*) as c1
  INTO tab 
  from CSV("https://rawgit.com/thephpleague/csv/master/examples/data/prenoms.csv");
  -- tab still empty!
  
  select *
  into HTML("#res1",{headers:true})
  from tab;

  --direct select works
  select count(*) as c1
  into HTML("#res2",{headers:true})
  from CSV("https://rawgit.com/thephpleague/csv/master/examples/data/prenoms.csv");

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  alasql('SOURCE "#sql"')
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interacting with a file will make the request async. At the moment the lib cant figure out how to wait for the response of an async statement in a multi-statement command.

To solve his you can use a promise notation for each async chuck of the total statement:

```
<script type="text/sql" id='sql'>
    CREATE table tab(c1 integer);

    select count(*) as c1
    INTO tab 
    from CSV("https://rawgit.com/thephpleague/csv/master/examples/data/prenoms.csv");
    -- tab still empty!
</script>
<script type="text/sql" id='sql2'>
    select *
    into HTML("#res1",{headers:true})
    from tab;

    --direct select works
    select count(*) as c1
    into HTML("#res2",{headers:true})
    from CSV("https://rawgit.com/thephpleague/csv/master/examples/data/prenoms.csv");

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alasql.promise(['SOURCE "#sql"','SOURCE "#sql2"'])
</script>
```